# Active record in codeigniter for fetching data from sql server?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter, activerecord

I connected SQL Server database successfully through CodeIgniter framework. I am able to use SQL queries directly but I want to use active record queries for fetching insertion or deletion then I get the following error:

> "Call to undefined method CI_DB_sqlsrv_driver::select()"

What does that mean? I am not able to use active records when using SQL Server db ? Or is there any other active record library for it?  
Can I use ACTIVE RECORDS of CodeIgniter for SQL Server? If yes, how?

This is not working:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('Persons');
$query = $this->db->get();
$data = $query->result();
print_r($data);
```

Only this way is working:

```
$db = $this->db->query('select * from Persons')->result();
print_r($db);
```

Comment: you should provide a litte bit more information - which CI version do you use ? post your `database.php`; Normally you should be able to use CI's Query Builder.but if you use some outdated version it might be possible that your driver isn't working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For More Info About **[Database Configuration](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/configuration.html?highlight=session)**

I tried with configuration change in `application/config/database.php`

```
$active_group = "default";
$active_record = TRUE;
$query_builder = TRUE;
```

and tried with clear cache.

Comment: It would be great if you explain it bro otherwise i will search it also

Comment: this is working of $active_record = TRUE;
$query_builder = TRUE;

Answer (score 0):

I you want to get all records than you don't need to write

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('Persons');
$query = $this->db->get();
$data = $query->result();
print_r($data);
```

You can simply get by using

```
$query = $this->db->get('Persons');
$data = $query->result();
print_r($data);
```